# How to specify the file type in a hard link

Tags: files, hard-link, html

Does anyone know how to specify the file type of a hard link? Is this even possible?

For example, I want to link to an HTML file (with content type `text/html`) in my website directory, so I used `ln path/to/html/file.html path/to/file/in/my/website/directory.html`, but the file type is detected as XML (via `file path/to/file/in/my/website/directory.html`). The site is stored on an S3 bucket if it matters.

Comment: And `file` on the original file gives you a different answer? Or did you not even try that?

Comment: `file` on the original file also gives me XML. Good point, and I think this question may be outside the scope of a hard link. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hard link means you simply add a second name for exactly the same file. Afterwards you cannot decide which name was first.

File names do not have a file type or content-type like `text/html`. The content type is something you web server makes up. It usually does so by looking at the extension of the file name. Have a look at the documentation of your web server.

The `file` command is something else. It will look at the content of the file and "guess" what the content looks like. If you have two file names linking to the same file, the `file` command sees the same content and therefore will give the same output.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "specify" a file type. A file is like a container containing stuff. That can be ASCII, binary or whatever. The utillity `file` just looks into it and "guesses" (with a pattern file called [magic](http://linux.die.net/man/5/magic)) whats inside.

You can only change the output of the `file` utillity by changing the file content to something that `file` guesses as HTML for example. If the file is a hardlink or a regular file doesn't change that behavior.